# Time-field name other than @timestamp does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

When I create an index in Kibana 5.0.0 and use @timestamp, I can create charts without any issue. However, if I select `mydatefield` (which is `date` type instead of `@timestamp` when creating an index, I cannot later create any chart. It says "No data" or something like this. What might be the reason? I uploaded data from CSV into Elasticsearch and specified datefield as follows:

```
mutate {
    add_field => {
        "mydatefield" => "%{mydatefield}"
        }
    }
    date
    {
    match => [ "mydatefield", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    target => "mydatefield"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the following:

1)`GET /_search
 {
 "query": 
             {
               "exists" : 
                  { 
                     "field" : "yourTimeField" 
                  } 
               }
 }`

If you get 0 result mean that all the documents with null value in this field.
If you get more that 0 result, check that the date is valid.

2)In kibana visualisation check that the time picker is set to the range of all your index

Comment: I checked the first point and I get this `"took": 33,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 12,
    "successful": 12,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 60718,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "registry",
        "_id": "2068978",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "MultiplateRate": "5",
          "TakenOn": "2017-03-25T08:32:12.000Z", ...`

Comment: Sorry, it's the same. It should be `mydatefield` in the thread.

Comment: Please post one document with the field mydatefield

Comment: One more comment: When I create Date Histogram per month and select Last 6 month in time picker (it was part of the problem), then I see the same month in X axis like: 2017-02-01
`2017-03-01
2017-04-01
2017-05-01
2017-06-01
2017-07-01`. Just days change. And there is only one bar.

Comment: Try to set the interval to auto(not month)

Comment: All your data it's in the same month, so kibana show you one bar

Comment: Oh, maybe that's indeed true. I though that I uploaded more data, though it seems that I only uploaded 1 month